# @mock.patch isn't raising an attribute error even after setting side_effect

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

[I'm attempting to fix a bug in the python package caniusepython3 which arises because distlib isn't parsing pypi projects correctly.](https://github.com/brettcannon/caniusepython3/issues/87) I've written this unit test

```
 @mock.patch('distlib.locators.locate')
 def test_blocking_dependencies_locators_fails(self, distlib_mock):
     """
     Testing the work around for //bitbucket.org/pypa/distlib/issue/59/
     """
     py3 = {'py3_project': ''}
     breaking_project = 'test_project'
     distlib_mock.locators.locate.return_value = "foo"
     distlib_mock.locators.locate.side_effect = AttributeError()
     got = dependencies.blocking_dependencies([breaking_project], py3)
     # If you'd like to test that a message is logged we can use 
     # testfixtures.LogCapture or stdout redirects.
```

[So that when distlib fixes the error in the next release of distlib the test case will still be valid.](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/distlib/issue/59/)

The problem is that the MagicMock never raises a AttributeError as I expected and instead returns a string representation of the magic mock object

```
try:
    # sets dist to <MagicMock name='locate()' id='4447530792'>
    dist = distlib.locators.locate(project)
except AttributeError:
    # This is a work around //bitbucket.org/pypa/distlib/issue/59/
    log.warning('{0} found but had to be skipped.'.format(project))
    continue
```

And causes this stack trace later on because it returns the object repr,

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Testing the work around for //bitbucket.org/pypa/distlib/issue/59/
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 1136, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/alexlord/git/caniusepython3/caniusepython3/test/test_dependencies.py", line 81, in test_blocking_dependencies_locators_fails
    got = dependencies.blocking_dependencies([breaking_project], py3)
  File "/Users/alexlord/git/caniusepython3/caniusepython3/dependencies.py", line 119, in blocking_dependencies
    return reasons_to_paths(reasons)
  File "/Users/alexlord/git/caniusepython3/caniusepython3/dependencies.py", line 43, in reasons_to_paths
    parent = reasons[blocker]
  File "/Users/alexlord/git/caniusepython3/caniusepython3/dependencies.py", line 29, in __getitem__
    return super(LowerDict, self).__getitem__(key.lower())
nose.proxy.KeyError: <MagicMock name='locate().name.lower().lower()' id='4345929400'>
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
ciu: INFO: Checking top-level project: test_project ...
ciu: INFO: Locating <MagicMock name='locate().name.lower()' id='4344734944'>
ciu: INFO: Dependencies of <MagicMock name='locate().name.lower()' id='4344734944'>: []
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

Why is the MagicMock not returning an exception when `distlib.locator.locate()` is called?

**Update:** I was able to get this unit test to work when I switched to using

```
def test_blocking_dependencies_locators_fails(self):
    """
    Testing the work around for //bitbucket.org/pypa/distlib/issue/59/
    """
    with mock.patch.object(distlib.locators, 'locate') as locate_mock:
        py3 = {'py3_project': ''}
        breaking_project = 'test_project'
        locate_mock.side_effect = AttributeError()
        got = dependencies.blocking_dependencies([breaking_project], py3)
        # If you'd like to test that a message is logged we can use 
        # testfixtures.LogCapture or stdout redirects.
```

But I'm still wondering what I did wrong with the decorator format.

Comment: What's up with all the dollar signs?

Comment: Extra characters from vim.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to test the `blocking_dependencies` function in the `dependencies` module, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `@mock.patch`, it mocks what you tell it, and passes that mock object as a parameter. Thus, your `distlib_mock` parameter *is* the mock `locate` function. You're effectively setting attributes on `distlib.locators.locate.locators.locate`. Set the attributes directly on the provided mock, and things should work better.

```
@mock.patch('distlib.locators.locate')
def test_blocking_dependencies_locators_fails(self, locate_mock):
    # ...
    locate_mock.return_value = "foo"
    locate_mock.side_effect = AttributeError()
    # ...
```